# Do genetic modifications exist to enhance the taste of tomatoes?

Tags: genetics, sensation

GM tomatoes seem less tasty. Has there been any research on GMOs with regard to taste?

Can scientists introduce a gene to, let's say, tomatoes, which would enhance the flavour? If not, why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is poorly researched.

Comment: I think the primary reason commercially available tomatoes have poor flavor has more to do with being bred for hardiness and stability while being shipped and on the shelf. These features were selected in favor of taste and were not added by what most consider "Genetic Modification"

Comment: If you trim this question down to the first two sentences I think it becomes quite good. Strong answers should probably consider geraniol synthase etc.

Comment: I have a feeling additives would be easier than genetically enhancing taste.

Comment: @GoodGravy If you could identify the "flavor genes" that were lost during breeding, you might be able to add them back while maintaining the hardiness. Whether or not this would be cost effective is another issue.

Comment: @user137 Flavour is a really ***really*** tough one from a genetic perspective. For example sugar content would be the result of several genes and their interactions between one another. Up-regulating some may not revert the flavour. Fibrosity would certainly be a similar story. Of course there is also the more subtle taste factors like metals and complicated carbohydrates which they are struggling with in artificial meat. I agree with your cost summary. Whereas there might be a single gene switch to make the crop drought-proof, taste is far more complex task for a far more trivial outcome.

Comment: @GoodGravy About the only thing I could think to do would be to compare the genome or transcriptome of poor tasting tomatoes to good tasting ones. This would probably produce a long list of differences to sort through.

Comment: @user137 You can see why additives might be simpler :P A simpler way yet would be selectively breeding the better tasting crops for a few generations and see if that sorts things out... Old school, but it doesn't involve a $1,000,000+ project!